# I'm trying to get data of customer using below code, it always return me null

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

```
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
assert post_id != null;
DatabaseReference database = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("RegisteredTrips").child(post_id).child("Customer");
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot noteDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            assert noteDataSnapshot != null;
            Customer value = noteDataSnapshot.getValue(Customer.class);
            data.add(value);


        }
        mListadapter = new ListAdapter(data);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mListadapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

[this is my firebase data tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXF2t.png)

Comment: Please add the content of your `Customer` class.

Comment: it gives me correct data of operator using same code ... i need help !

Comment: RegisteredTrips
-LtyYDoJ8IU_doibw7kn
Customer
aiQHl4XTu2VRjUXWifGlnXmC3NA2
user_address: 
"f8 markaz"
user_email: 
"faheemnalik525@gmail.com"
user_name: 
"Faheem"
user_phone: 
"03360510919"
cnic: 
"123412341234"
email: 
"zarkahmed14@gmail.com"
name: 
"zark ahmed"
op_id: 
"aPgIEvJlCScebvT59kaO6eG8I4v2"
operator
phone: 
"0336051019"
postDate: 
"13/12/19"
postDescrpition: 
"We are arranging a 4 day trip to sawat and mala..."
postDestination: 
"Sawat and Malamjabba"
postId: 
"-LtyYDoJ8IU_doibw7kn"
postPrice: 
"12000"
postTitle: 
"Sawat Trip r days"

Comment: Please edit your question to include: 1) the `Customer` class, as Alex already asked, 2) the JSON as text, instead of as a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).